# Puppeteer iFrame handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, iframe, puppeteer, selector

Im just experimenting with Puppeteer and now Im trying to automatically fill out the Shopify Payment field for testing.
The html code:
[image: Part1]
[image: Part2]

Its reproducible by just simply go to any shopify site, add a product to cart and on the last step you have to enter the payment details.

I tried to fill out the "Card number" field like this:

```
const ccccHandle = await page.$('#number iframe');
const ccccframe = await ccccHandle.contentFrame();
await ccccframe.type('input[type=text]', cardNumberValue, { delay: 1000 });
```

But its not working. I even tried a slight delay before filling out, but nothing changed.I handled an iFrame like this on another site already and it worked. Why does it not work here?
How can i fix this?

Comment: _the Shopify Payment field_  -- could you share a link to this as well as a [mcve]? Thanks.

Comment: With such little information you have giving us It would be hard to answer the question.

Comment: @ggorlen I added a Screenshot. Its 
reproducible by just simply go to any shopify site, add a product to cart and on the last step you have to enter the payment details.

Answer (score 3):

Like i said It's a little hard to answer the question with such little information you have giving us.

But you can give this a try.

---

Undated:

```
  let browser, page;
  let pageUrl = 'https://The-Page-Url-Here.com';

  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(pageUrl, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded', timeout: 60000 });

    await page.waitForSelector('body > iframe', { timeout: 60000 });

    const elementHandle = await page.$('body > iframe');
    const frame = await elementHandle.contentFrame();
    await frame.waitForSelector('input[id="number"]');
    frame.$eval('input[id="number"]', el => el.value = 'CardNumberValueHere');
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  } finally {
    if (browser) {
      await browser.close();
      console.log('closing browser');
    }
  }
```

Or you use `page.evaluate` example below.

```
  let browser, page;
  let pageUrl = 'https://The-Page-Url-Here.com';

  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(pageUrl, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded', timeout: 60000 });

     await page.waitForSelector('body > iframe', { timeout: 60000 });

     await page.evaluate(() => {
       const elementHandle = document.querySelector('body > iframe');
       const frame =  elementHandle.contentWindow.document.body.querySelector('input[id="number"]');
       frame.value = 'CardNumberValueHere'
    });
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  } finally {
    if (browser) {
      await browser.close();
      console.log('closing browser');
    }
  }
```

Or you could give this a try.

```
  let browser, page;
  let pageUrl = 'https://The-Page-Url-Here.com';

  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(pageUrl, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded', timeout: 60000 });

    const iframe = await page.waitForSelector('body > iframe');
    const frame = await iframe.contentFrame();
    await frame.type('input[id="number"]', 'CardNumberValueHere');
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  } finally {
    if (browser) {
      await browser.close();
      console.log('closing browser');
    }
  }
```

Comment: sorry for the late answer. The selector for the iFrame is 'body > iframe:nth-child(9)', the #number is the id for the Input Field I want to fill out. I added a screenshot, and how to reproduce it above.

Comment: I checked with logs, and the problem is, that it doesnt get the input[id="number"]. There it always crashes. I dont want to post the full html of the site, but you can check yourself on e.g. https://partakefoods.com/ . On the last step do you find the html. Thanks for your help

Comment: Every time i get to the payment page / form it takes me back to the page asking for my information. Have you tried screenshotting the page?

Comment: I added screenshots of the affected html code